# How to avoid duplicated classes in classes with defined fields and no methods

Tags: java, json, class, design-patterns, pojo

I have a lot of similar classes to create with defined fields, no need constructors, methods.

Sample classes:

```
public class Adam {
   private String name = "Adam";
   private int code = 1;
}

public class Brian {
   private String name = "Brian";
   private int code = 2;
}
```

and about 100 or more similar classes, 12 fields in class. All defined.

I would like to have access like eq: Class.fieldname or similar handy way.

Later I want to make a json object using this class like

```
{ name: "Adam", code: "1" }
```

and use it in rest assured framework: https://rest-assured.io/

Maybe storing this kind of data as classes in not good solution? any idea?

PS: no possibility to keep them in dB.

Comment: Just use [inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: These should all be values of the same class, not separate classes.

Comment: You should just store the data in _JSON_ format, rather than parsing it to and from classes.

Comment: 100 classes, each with the same 12 fields? Why? Sounds like there is some sort of design flaw, possibly an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems very inefficient in code reuse. You should have a Person class or something similar. Each person should be an instance. Since Java 14 you can simplify this usage with the use of the `record` keyword.

Example:

```java
public record Person (String name, int code) {}
```

Getter/setters are autogenerated.

```java
p = new Person("Adam", 1);
p.name() // returns name
```

If `code` is an unique id then you can use a Map or Vector to keep track of the instances.

Comment: You are already creating 100 classes individually, which is not the expected usage. They are called classes for a reason.

Comment: Yeah I aggree, but this way : p = new Person("Adam", 1) I need to create 100 similar objects, There is no unique filed like id in classes, only filed like name, code or few simmilar. Generally imagine that i want to have a handy represantation of 100 jsons stored in code.  No need any modification on classess, no setters. It would be stored as jsons- escaped strings but It is not  easy usable.

Comment: so maybe it is a better way insted of classes?

Comment: That is not the same scenario that was described in the question. You could use some resource file (properties, JSON, YAML, whatever), read it, parse it and create the structure in memory.